# Neo4j as data source for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, neo4j, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a requirement wherein I've to pull data from Neo4j and create Spark RDD's out of that data. I'm using Python in my project. There is [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) connector for the same purpose but it's written in Scala. So I can think of following workarounds for now -

1. Query data from neo4j in small chunks/batches, convert each chunk to Spark RDD using `parallize()` method. Finally merge/combine all the RDD's using `union()` method to get single RDD. And then I can do transformations & actions on them.
2. Another approach is to read data from Neo4j and create a Kafka producer out of it. Then use Kafka as a data source for Spark. e.g.

> Neo4j -> Kafka -> Spark

I want to know that which one is more efficient for large chunks of data? and if there is any better approach for solving this problem, please help me out with that.

Note: I do tried to extend pyspark API in order to create custom RDD in python. pyspark is API is very different as compared to Spark's Scala/Java API. In case of Scala API's, custom RDD can be created by extending `RDD` class and overriding `compute()` and `getPartitions()` methods. But in pyspark API, I couldn't find `compute()` under `RDD` class in `rdd.py`

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/04/14/spark-generating-csv-files-to-import-into-neo4j/) by Michael Hunger talks about using Spark to get CSV data *into* Neo4j, but maybe some of the Spark code will help you out. Also there is [Mazerunner](https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/#mazerunner) which is a Spark/Neo4j/GraphX integrated tool for using Spark to pass subgraphs to Neo4j.

Comment: I want to pull data from neo4j and pass it to spark.